# Java DBunit not null assertion for given column

Tags: dbunit

I'm using DBUnit for testing my DAO layer. One of the columns that I have to validate, contains XML document. Is it possible that for that particular column I do something like not null assertion using DBUnit? I don't want to make strict assertion as this XML contains some dynamic values like timestamps etc.